# Bootstrap Icon alignment with input group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have n input group like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
<input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
</div>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: username input group]

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXzYXg).

I am using jQuery validation which adds an error class with an error message, but this stretches the prepended icon.

html with error:

```
<div class="input-group has-error">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
<input class="form-control error" id="username" name="username" type="text">
<span class="help-block form-error">This user name is already registered.</span></div>
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image: User name with error]

How can I keep the icon the same height and include the error message inline?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the error message outside `input-group`

Check Demo [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/QKQRxX)

Try this:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#registration-form').validate({
      rules: {
        name: {
          required: true,
          required: true
        },

        username: {
          minlength: 6,
          required: true
        },
        phone: {
          minlength: 8,
          required: true
        },
        password: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 6
        },
        confirm_password: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 6,
          equalTo: "#password"
        },

        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },

        address: {
          minlength: 10,
          required: true
        },

        agree: "required"

      },
      highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
      },
      unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
      },
      errorElement: 'span',
      errorClass: 'help-block',
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
          error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
          error.insertAfter(element);
        }
      },
      success: function(label) {
        label.addClass("valid").text("Ok!")
      }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do some styling in your input box !
try this :

```
<div class="input-group has-error">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
<input class="form-control error" id="username" name="username" type="text" style="height: auto;">
<span class="help-block form-error">This user name is already registered.</span></div>
```